# Changing React Theme Context on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, components

Main.js

```
import React from "react"
//import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import ThemeContext from "./ThemeContext"

function Button(props) {
    return (
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
            {theme => (
                <button className={`${theme}-theme`}>Switch Theme</button>
            )}
        </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    )    
}

export default Button
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import ThemeContext from "./ThemeContext"



ReactDOM.render(
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={"dark"}>
       <App /> 
    </ThemeContext.Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Hello all, I am trying to get a handle on using Contexts with React. I have the code above that I am trying to do a basic change of the theme from light to dark.
Right now, I can manually change the theme of my page if I change the 'dark' to 'light', but I just want to be able to do this by clicking the button. It has been very frustrating today to try to get to work and I have googled a lot but everything that I found was a little more complex and I guess I was unable to understand. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about passing down a callback to change the theme along with your theme data in the context? Something like:

```
// Wraps the previous theme provider render
class Root extends Component {
  // Store theme in state
  state = {
    theme: "dark"
  };

  // Callback to change it
  changeTheme = newTheme => {
    this.setState({ theme: newTheme });
  };

  render() {
    const { theme } = this.state;
    // Here pass down an object instead of a string with both the theme string and the callback
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme: theme, changeTheme: this.changeTheme }}>
        <App />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

function Button(props) {
  return (
    // your consumer now gets both the theme and the callback
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {({ theme, changeTheme }) => (
        <button
          onClick={() => changeTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark")}
          className={`${theme}-theme`}
        >
          Switch Theme
        </button>
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  );
}

// Finally just render the root
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById("root"));
```